# refractored onclick function does not run

Tags: javascript

So, I made a basic onclick toggle page. I wrote code that works, but when I try to refactor it, it does not work. Can someone point out why and how to fix it?

I tried the refactored JS for just one image--why try it for all images when the first one won't work.

I will attach the HTML, the working JS and refactored JS. I wont include ALL the JS from the file that works. I will provide the code that toggles the first image (that I reused to toggle the next five images).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css"  href="#">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Dogs to Cats</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dog to Cat Magic!</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <img id ="whiteLab" src="whiteLab.jpg" alt="White Lab">
        <img id ="waterDog" src="waterDog.jpg" alt="Water Dog">
        <img id ="spanielBall" src="spanielBall.jpg" alt="Spaniel with a 
ball">
        <img id="glassesDog" src="glassesDog.jpg" alt="Dog with glasses">
        <img id="brownLab" src="brownLab.jpg" alt="Brown Lab">
        <img id="tiredDog" src="tiredDog.jpg" alt="Tired dog">
    </div>
 <script src="newdogs.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>

//seperate JS document

let whiteLab = document.getElementById("whiteLab");
let whiteLabImage = "whiteLab.jpg";
let fatCat = "fatCat.jpg";
let image_tracker = "whiteLab";

whiteLab.onclick = function(){

if(image_tracker === "whiteLab"){
    whiteLab.src = fatCat;
    image_tracker = "fatCat";
}else{
    whiteLab.src = whiteLabImage;
    image_tracker ="whiteLab";
}
};

//seperate JS document

let whiteLab = document.getElementById("whiteLab");
let whiteLabImage = "whiteLab.jpg"
let fatCat = "fatCat.jpg"
let image_tracker = "whiteLab";

const dogClicker = function (image_tracker, dogsrc, dogImage, catImage){
if (image_tracker === "whiteLab"){
     dogsrc.src = catImage;
     image_tracker = "fatCat";
} else{
    dogsrc.src =dogImage;
    image_tracker = "whiteLab"
};
};


whiteLab.onclick = dogClicker(image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, 
fatCat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because one of the parameters of the function **dogClicker()** and a global variable have the same name - **image_tracker**. Better make your function's parameter variables unique or alter the global variable directly without passing it to the function at all.

Also if you add the click event listener like this:

```
whiteLab.onclick = dogClicker(image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, 
fatCat);
```

the callback function will be called at least one time no matter if the user actually clicked on it or not.

Better do it like this:

```
whiteLab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  dogClicker(image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, fatCat);
});
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
let whiteLab = document.getElementById("whiteLab");
let whiteLabImage = "https://picsum.photos/id/735/200/300"
let fatCat = "https://picsum.photos/id/75/200/300"
let image_tracker = "whiteLab";

function dogClicker(imgTrck, dogsrc, dogImage, catImage) {
  if (imgTrck == "whiteLab") {
    dogsrc.src = catImage;
    image_tracker = "fatCat";
  } else {
    dogsrc.src = dogImage;
    image_tracker = "whiteLab"
  }
}

whiteLab.addEventListener("click", function() {
  dogClicker(image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, fatCat);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dogs.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Dog to Cat Magic!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <img id="whiteLab" src="https://picsum.photos/id/735/200/300" alt="White Lab">
  <img id="waterDog" src="waterDog.jpg" alt="Water Dog">
  <img id="spanielBall" src="spanielBall.jpg" alt="Spaniel with a 
ball">
  <img id="glassesDog" src="glassesDog.jpg" alt="Dog with glasses">
  <img id="brownLab" src="brownLab.jpg" alt="Brown Lab">
  <img id="tiredDog" src="tiredDog.jpg" alt="Tired dog">
</div>
```

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! =)

Answer (score 0):

the way you are assigning the *whiteLab.onclick* is wrong.

The line whiteLab.onclick = dogClicker(image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, 
fatCat);

Will invoke the "dogClicker" function and will assign the returned value to on click, instead of assigning the function reference to whiteLab.onclick

instead please use the bind method.

whiteLab.onclick = dogClicker.bind(null,image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, 
fatCat);

Also, please always check the console log for errors. They are very helpful. You have declared the variables in both the js file, the declaration statement in the second js file will throw error as the variables are already declared with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

So, I used obscure's recommendation and got it to work! I'll post it here so that anyone else can read the comments here, see my code and hopefully understand how it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css"  href="#">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Dogs to Cats</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dog to Cat Magic!</h1>
<div class="container">
    <img id ="whiteLab" src="whiteLab.jpg" alt="White Lab">
    <img id ="waterDog" src="waterDog.jpg" alt="Water Dog">
    <img id ="spanielBall" src="spanielBall.jpg" alt="Spaniel with a 
ball">
    <img id="glassesDog" src="glassesDog.jpg" alt="Dog with glasses">
    <img id="brownLab" src="brownLab.jpg" alt="Brown Lab">
    <img id="tiredDog" src="tiredDog.jpg" alt="Tired dog">
 </div>
 <script src="newdogs.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>


let whiteLab = document.getElementById("whiteLab");
let whiteLabImage = "whiteLab.jpg";
let fatCat = "fatCat.jpg";
let image_tracker = "whiteLab";

let waterDog = document.getElementById("waterDog");
let waterDogImage = "waterDog.jpg";
let travelCat = "travelCat.jpg";

let spanielBall = document.getElementById("spanielBall");
let spanielBallImage = "spanielBall.jpg";
let giveMeCat = "giveMeCat.jpg";

let glassesDog = document.getElementById("glassesDog");
let glassesDogImage = "glassesDog.jpg";
let noEarsCat = "noEarsCat.jpg";

let brownLab = document.getElementById("brownLab");
let brownLabImage = "brownLab.jpg";
let butterFly = "catButteryfly.jpg";

let tiredDog = document.getElementById("tiredDog");
let tiredDogImage = "tiredDog.jpg";
let smilingCat = "smilingCat.jpg"

function dogClicker(imgTrck, dogsrc, dogImage, catImage) {
if (imgTrck == "whiteLab") {
  dogsrc.src = catImage;
  image_tracker = "fatCat";
} else {
  dogsrc.src = dogImage;
  image_tracker = "whiteLab";
}
} 

whiteLab.addEventListener("click", function() {
dogClicker(image_tracker, whiteLab, whiteLabImage, fatCat);
 });

waterDog.addEventListener("click", function(){
  dogClicker(image_tracker, waterDog, waterDogImage, travelCat);
} );

spanielBall.addEventListener("click", function(){
dogClicker(image_tracker, spanielBall, spanielBallImage, giveMeCat)
});

glassesDog.addEventListener("click", function(){
    dogClicker(image_tracker, glassesDog, glassesDogImage, noEarsCat)
});

brownLab.addEventListener("click", function(){
    dogClicker(image_tracker, brownLab, brownLabImage, butterFly)
});

tiredDog.addEventListener("click", function (){
    dogClicker(image_tracker, tiredDog, tiredDogImage, smilingCat)
});
```